# How to fix "package com.sun.webkit is not visible" combile error using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to use `comb.sun.webkit` package in Java 10, but I keep getting the error at compilation:

```
package com.sun.webkit is not visible(package com.sun.webkit is declared in module javafx.web, which does not export it)
```

I tried to fix it by modifying the gradle script:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = ['--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```

To my knowledge we are not using modules (no `module-info.java` in the project) so it should work. Yet, I still get the same error even with the `jvmArgs` specified.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add that argument to the compiler as well.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `compileJava { options.compilerArgs .... }`